# ¿Cómo hago un subquery en Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, querybuilder

Tengo la siguiente consulta y estoy intentando convertirla a través de QueryBuilder:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) from (
        SELECT COUNT (V.CORRELATIVO) AS CANTIDAD
        FROM CLIENTES C
        LEFT JOIN VENTAS V
        ON V.CLIENTE_CODIGO = C.codigo
        WHERE C.CODIGO <> '01'
        GROUP BY C.CODIGO
        HAVING COUNT (V.correlativo) > 1
    )
```

Hasta los momentos he hecho lo siguiente:

```
private function getFrequent(){
    $frequent = DB::table('CLIENTES')
    ->leftJoin('VENTAS', 'VENTAS.CLIENTE_CODIGO', '=','CLIENTES.CODIGO')
    ->select (DB::raw('COUNT(VENTAS.CORRELATIVO) AS CANTIDAD'))
    ->where('CLIENTES.CODIGO', '<>', '01')
    //->where ('VENTAS.TIPO_DOCUMENTO','=','FAC')
    ->groupBy('CLIENTES.CODIGO')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(VENTAS.CORRELATIVO) > 1');
    return $frequent;
}
```

Sin embargo, me faltaría agregarle el SELECT COUNT (*) que tengo afuera, no encuentro como agregar ese faltante.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tu quieres realizar con eloquent yo lo intente algunas veces pero me parecio mucho mas sencillo  ejecutar la consulta directamente

```
$sentence =  "SELECT COUNT(*) from (SELECT COUNT (V.CORRELATIVO) AS 
              CANTIDAD   
              FROM LIENTES C 
              LEFT JOIN VENTAS V ON V.CLIENTE_CODIGO = C.codigo 
              WHERE C.CODIGO <> '01' 
              GROUP BY C.CODIGO HAVING COUNT (V.correlativo) > 1 )";
$result  =  DB::select($sentence);
```

o Mas bien puedes crear una vista y hacer la consulta sobre la vistas

```
create view vista_sentence as SELECT COUNT(*) 
                              from (SELECT COUNT (V.CORRELATIVO) AS 
                              CANTIDAD   
                              FROM LIENTES C 
                              LEFT JOIN VENTAS V 
                              ON V.CLIENTE_CODIGO = C.codigo 
                              WHERE C.CODIGO <> '01' 
                              GROUP BY C.CODIGO 
                              HAVING COUNT (V.correlativo) > 1 )";
```

Luego crearías un modelo que relacione la vista o simplemente la consultas con **query builder**

```
$operacion = DB::table('vista_sentence')
```

para poder hacer esto debes habilitar lo siguiente  `"PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true"` en el archivo database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
             'options'   => [
                \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
            ]
        ],
```